# How to save background color using color picker?

Tags: jquery, css, colors, color-picker, picker

I'm new in using jquery cookie,can you guys please help me..I tried using almost every single example that i found here and searching on google but no results. 
How can i save the background-color by using this http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/ color picker ?
I'm using this example:

```
<pre><code>
$('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
    color: '#0000ff',
    onShow: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
        return false;
    },
    onHide: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
        return false;
    },
    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
        $('#colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
    }
});</code></pre>
```

EDIT:
Steps i have done so far,but now the background color it doesn't change anymore:

1. i've included the jquery.cookie.js file right before the color picker call
2. I've changed the above code into this

   ```
   if($.cookie('my_color')) {
       $('#colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor',$.cookie('my_color'));
   }

   $('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
       color: '#0000ff',
       onShow: function (colpkr) {
           $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
           return false;
       },
       onHide: function (colpkr) {
           $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
           return false;
       },
       onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {            
               $.cookie('my_color', '#' + hex, { expires: 365 });
       }
   });
   ```

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Nobody ? :( ..common guys please help me.